# Regex Check Whether a string contains characters other than specified

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

How to check whether a string contains character **other than**:

- Alphabets(Lowe-Case/Upper-Case)
- digits
- Space
- Comma(**,**)
- Period (**.**)
- Bracket **(**    **)**
- **&**
- **'**
- **$**
- **+**(plus) minus(**-**) (*****)  (**=**) arithmetic operator
- **/**

using regular expression in ColdFusion?

I want to  make sure a string doesn't contain even single character other than the specified.

Comment: I have edited my answer a little bit for more clarification, please let me know if there is any problems ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find if there are any invalid characters like this:

```
<cfif refind( "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&'$()\-+*=/]" , Input ) >

    <!--- invalid character found --->

</cfif>
```

Where the `[`...`]` is a character class (match any single char from within), and the `^` at the start means "NOT" - i.e. if it finds anything that is not an accepted char, it returns true.

I don't understand "Small Bracket(opening closing)", but guess you mean `<` and `>` there? If you want `()` or `{}` just swap them over. For `[]` you need to escape them as `\[\]`

**Character Class Escaping**

Inside a character class, only a handful of characters need escaping with a backslash, these are:

- `\` - if you want a literal backslash, escape it.
- `^` - a caret must be escaped if it's the first character, otherwise it negates the class.
- `-` - a dash creates a range. It must be escaped unless first/last (but recommended always to be)
- `[` and `]` - both brackets should be escaped.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Is this correct?  "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&'$()-+=_/]"   . I am not sure about the characters that we need to escapes.

Comment: Almost. You need to escape the `-` otherwise it creates a range between `)` and `+` (so means `*` gets included. (i.e. `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&'$()\-+=_/]`). I updated the answer with some notes on the five characters which characters need escaping inside a character class.

Comment: (Actually, just seen the updated question says `*` should be included, so technically what you want would work, but it's still clearer to escape the dash and explicitly include the asterisk.)

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion uses Java's engine to parse regular expressions, anyway to make sure a string doesn't contain one of the characters you mentioned then try:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&$']*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&$']).*$
```

The above expression would only work if you are parsing the file line by line. If you want to apply this to text which contains multiple lines then you need to use the global modifier and the multi-line modifier and change the expression a bit like this:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&$']*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&$'\r\n]).*$
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fR9jP4)

Comment: Coldfusion can access Java's regex engine, but it's built-in function use Apache ORO engine. Also, your expression is over-complex and doesn't match the characters currently described in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression:

```
[^][a-zA-Z0-9 ,.&'$]
```

will match if the string contains any characters other than the ones in your list.